# How to disable MediaWiki user account from the wiki website as an administrator

Tags: web, mediawiki, wiki

I'm the administrator of a wiki that's only accessible via login from a user with an account. I need to remove/disable/delete a user, but from the special pages on the website, I only seem to be able to delete their contributions and block the user. What I want is to prevent the user from ever being able to login and I've seen a few solutions such as changing their password and merging his account with someone else but those options seem to be accessible only via the Mediawiki software, which I've been having trouble installing. So is there any way to do this on the website itself?

Answer (score 1):

Set [`$wgBlockDisablesLogin`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgBlockDisablesLogin) to `true` and block the account.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to making wiki websites. Is there a way to input that command somewhere on the website or is that a command for the MediaWiki software? If its the latter, I can't seem to gt my MediaWiki to work so I've been looking for a way to do this on the actual website.

Thanks

Comment: It's a configuration setting that you typically add to [`LocalSettings.php`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:LocalSettings.php).